# Regular expressions: re.sub(), \b and cyrillic characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, cyrillic

I'm trying to replace whole appearance of cyrillic word in text:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
S = u"раз Два трИ".lower()
print re.sub(ur"\bдва\b", u"четыре", S, re.U)
```

Prints "раз два три" while "раз четыре три" is expected.

At the same time search() and findall() works well:

```
print re.search(ur"\bдва\b", S, re.U).group(0)
print re.findall(ur"\bдва\b", S, re.U)
```

So the only problem with re.sub()

Latin chars work well:

```
S = u"one Two threE".lower()
print re.sub(ur"\btwo\b", u"four", S, re.U)
```

If I try the following way, it swallows spaces (and looks ugly:

```
print re.sub(u"[^а-яё\d]два[^а-яё\d]", u"четыре", S)
```

A try to keep spaces doesn't work:

```
print re.sub(u"(?:[^а-яё\d])(два)(?:[^а-яё\d])", u"четыре", S)
```

Replace doesn't help too:

```
S = u"раз Два трИ".lower()
print S
S.replace(u"два", u"четыре")
print S
```

Prints "раз два три" two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass flags with keyword argument `flags`:

```
In [3]: S = u"раз Два трИ".lower()
In [5]: print re.sub(ur"\bдва\b", u"четыре", S, flags=re.U)
раз четыре три
```